# Accepted Burp Suite Certificate, Still Gives SSL warnings

Tags: iphone, network, keychain, proxy

I'm trying to proxy my traffic through my VM's instance of Burp Suite. I basically configured proxy settings via wifi settings on my iPhone to point to my VM (it's bridged). I can see some HTTP traffic go through Burp Suite in my VM, but HTTPS connections give me a SSL certificate verification error.

I navigated to https://burp, clicked on CA certificate, installed it, and tried to browse to SSL sites again. I get the same issue. To my understanding, because I trusted this certificate, I should be able to navigate to any SSL site. At least this works 100% for me on the desktop. Unfortunately I just can't do what I'm trying to do from the desktop and need to proxy through my phone.

Any suggestions as to why installing SSL cetificates on my iPhone isn't recognizing this certificate even though it's installed and trusted?